# Want to combine three separate append queries and have final results displayed on single row

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I am trying to do a series of calculations based on user inputted data:

1. The first query is an append query that multiples a field by two
2. The second query then takes the result from the first query and divides it by a field in a second table
3. The last query takes the result from the 2nd query and adds it to another field from the second table

I am running into two issues:

1. I'd like to merge all three queries into a single query and be able to fire it with a single button click.
2. I would like all three values calculated to be added on the same row. Currently, I am producing four rows of data, and the third row is an incorrect value.

Query 1:

```
INSERT INTO [Exit Plan] ( riskAdjustedTotal )
SELECT [Trade Overview].totalAcceptableLoss * 2
FROM [Trade Overview];
```

Query 2:

```
INSERT INTO [Exit Plan] ( stockPriceIncrease )
SELECT ([Exit Plan].riskAdjustedTotal/[Trade Overview].stocksPurchased)
FROM [Trade Overview], [Exit Plan];
```

Query 3:

```
INSERT INTO [Exit Plan] ( targetSellPrice )
SELECT ([Exit Plan].stockPriceIncrease + [Trade Overview].entryTrigger)
FROM [Trade Overview], [Exit Plan];
```

Appreciate any and all help

Comment: Use INSERT to create record then use UPDATE to modify data.

Answer (score 1):

No need to insert into. You can just name the query whatever the table name you want and use it as if its a table. That way it dynamically updates as your data does and you don't need to reprocess it. (unless you want to capture a point in time transaction)

```
SELECT 
([Trade Overview].totalAcceptableLoss * 2) as riskAdjustedTotal,
(([Trade Overview].totalAcceptableLoss * 2)/[Trade Overview].stocksPurchased) as stockPriceIncrease,
(([Trade Overview].totalAcceptableLoss * 2)/[Trade Overview].stocksPurchased)+ [Trade Overview].entryTrigger as targetSellPrice 
FROM [Trade Overview];
```

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you very much for answering the question so concisely!

Comment: If answer resolves issue, please mark accepted. Upvote would be nice as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this can help

```
INSERT INTO ("your table name")
SELECT (stockPriceIncrease + [Trade Overview].entryTrigger) AS targetSellPrice, stockPriceIncrease, riskAdjustedTotal
FROM (SELECT (riskAdjustedTotal/[Trade Overview].stocksPurchased) AS stockPriceIncrease, riskAdjustedTotal
FROM (SELECT ([Trade Overview].totalAcceptableLoss) * 2 AS riskAdjustedTotal
FROM [Trade Overview]))
```